# How to change the Drupal 7 Image-Field title textfield to textarea?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

function is: `image_field_widget_process (image.field.inc)` I want:

`$element['title'] = array('#type' => 'textfield')`

to

`$element['title'] = array('#type' => 'textarea')`

how I get it without hack the drupal core code?

maybe: `form_alter + #process #after_build` or `theme_textfield` ??

Comment: try template.php and there the preprocess functions should be usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an easy way to get it. This is achieved by overwriting the **theme_image_widget** function:

```
function yourtemplatename_image_widget($vars){
    //$vars['element']['title']['#type'] = 'textarea';    // not works
    $vars['element']['title']['#theme'] = 'textarea';    // works !!
    return theme_image_widget($vars);
}
```

That's all. But I don't know how to change the image uploading directory in this case. Can anyone help me ?